# Redirect loop caused by django middleware

Tags: python, django, redirect, middleware, django-middleware

I am trying to redirect users right after signup to go to a terms of agreement page.

This is my Middleware class:

```
class TermsMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.profile.filled_terms is None:
            return redirect(reverse('terms'))
```

I am getting the following error which I can confirm from a quick glance at my server:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

I have a Profile model class with a filled_terms field.

I have a term template that is working just fine when I go to it manually.

Also here is my url matcher:

```
url(r'^terms/', 'hana.views.terms', name='terms')
```

How can I get out of this redirect loop and have users on signup be redirected with the middleware to terms of agreement page?

Comment: In order to prevent bad url matches, add a dollar sign `$` right after the `/`, like this: `url(r'^terms/$', 'hana.views.terms', name='terms')`. With that change you're saying: hey the `/` is the final character of my url.

Comment: hmm thanks. That doesn't solve the redirect problem though. Because in every request user get redirected to terms page even before terms page can load so user never have chance to accept terms. So hence why continuous loop

Comment: Does the terms page rendered? Or term page is another redirect?`

Comment: it redirects before it has a chance to render

Answer (score 6):

Well, also the requests to the terms page are processed, and if `filled_terms` is `None`, it redirects to the Terms page, which... and that is your loop.

So one way to go about this is to check in the middleware if the current request is for the path of the redirect page:

```
class TermsMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.profile.filled_terms is None:
            if not request.path == reverse('terms'):
                return redirect(reverse('terms'))
```

That way you only perform a redirect if the request is not for the redirect page already.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: A bit of an optimization is setting a variable to the reverse value and then using it in the if check and the redirect return. This was useful for me to do this for many urls and only having to write the if and return statement once.